# Importerror:No module named in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I created a file named hello.py in /home/Desktop/problems directory
and i want to import it to a file present in /home/Desktop/PP

```
#hello.py file
def matrix():
  print "enter into matrix"
```

and i want to access this hello.py file in a file named new.py
so i did like this..

```
#new.py file
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/Desktop/problems"))
from hello import *
matrix()
```

But i am getting an error like no module named new

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: The directory order was wrong..so it was giving the error.. it should have been /home/valac/Desktop/problems !!

Answer (score 0):

I created both files with the content described here and I ran your new.py:

```
python new.py
```

And it worked just fine. How are you executing or using your new.py script? The problem is probably related to that. Can you explain how are you using new.py?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have init file in the pp folder? You may create **init**.py under folder pp.

The **init**.py does not need to contain any code. It will change the folder as a module.

Comment: yeah..i created a file in the command line : touch  __init.py__  ..in the corresponding folder..but it still is giving me the same error.

Comment: The following folder structure was based on windows.

Comment: Assume the folder path is C:\Users\abc\folder\stackoverflow\pp and C:\Users\abc\folder\stackoverflow\problems.   Then in your new.py you may use the following code:

Comment: import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\abc\\folder\\stackoverflow\\pp') 
import hello
hello.matrix()